# Dynamically create appenders in logback.xml

Tags: java, logback

I want to separate each package's logs in their own file without having to create multiple appenders for each file as the appenders will look exactly the same except the file name.

The idea would be to create a logger for each package and set a custom property in each logger to use as an argument in the appender.
Something like this:

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="logFile" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>${arg1}</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss} %logger{100} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.example.myPackage1" level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="logFile" arg1="package1.log"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="com.example.myPackage2" level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="logFile" arg1="package2.log"/>
    </logger>
</configuration>
```

But this configuration just makes me a file named `arg1_IS_UNDEFINED` instead of the `package1.log` and `package2.log` that I intended, which I assume is because the appender does not recognize this `arg1` that I just made up.

I also tried to set this `arg1` with the `<property>` tag inside of each logger but I got the same result

Is there any way to do what I want perhaps with a different syntax?

Comment: I don't if this can be done via XML configuration, but given your goal, you may want to consider [programmatic configuration](https://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/classic/spi/Configurator.html) instead.